# Unable to send SMS by Twilo integration in salesforce

Tags: integration, sms, twilio

I've install the twilo library in salesforce from [Github](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-salesforce) by using quick install link. 
and create Sample VF page as below;

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" Extensions="Send_SMS_Controller"
showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
 <apex:form >
       <apex:pageBlock id="msgs"> 
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
             Body : <br/>
            <apex:inputText id="smsBody" value="{!smsBody}"   
  style="width:400px; height:50px;"/>
                   <br/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!send}" value="Send" 
 id="sendButton" reRender="msgs" rendered="{!hasNumber}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!getReturn}" value="Return to Account"
  id="returnButton" reRender="msgs" rendered="{!NOT(hasNumber)}"/>
         </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
```

And controller is

```
public class Send_SMS_Controller {
public String smsBody {get; set;}
public boolean hasNumber {get; set;}
private final String  fromNumber = '+13343779137';// get it from twilio
  //after login click Phone Numbers tab in left sidebar

private string dialCode = '+91'; // Add your dial Code of your country.
public Send_SMS_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
   hasNumber = true;
}
public PageReference Send()
{
    String account = '******************'; // Account SID on home tab
    String token   =   'd7e5688cde62d1f27c2aeaed9f03aa3a';//AUTH Token on home tab
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(account, token);

    Id accountId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    String baseUrl = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm();
    Account a = [select Phone from Account where Id = :accountId];

    if(a.Phone != null)
    {
        String phoneNumber = a.Phone;
        if(!phoneNumber.Contains(dialCode))
        phoneNumber = dialCode+phoneNumber;// If by default dialCode is not 
         //on Phone number we will ad it.
        System.debug('phoneNumber'+phoneNumber);
         Map<String,String> params = new Map<String,String> {
        'To'   => phoneNumber,
        'From' => fromNumber,
        'Body' => smsBody
         };
         TwilioSMS sms = client.getAccount().getSMSMessages().create(params);
    }
    else
    {
         ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'This Account have No Phone Number Click Return to Account'));
         System.debug('Message is set');
         hasNumber = false;
         return null;
    }

    pagereference redirect = new PageReference(baseUrl+'/'+accountId);
    return redirect;
}
 public PageReference getReturn()
 {
    return new PageReference(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/'+ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'));
 }

}
```

Its throwing me error,

> The From phone number +13343779137 is not a valid, SMS-capable inbound phone number or short code for your account.

Above no. is verified, as i'm using trial account. 
[image]

Please suggest me solution to resolve the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out this link

[SMS Error](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/21606)

You are using a trial account which means your from number should be `+15005550006` and to number should be your verified number(the number you want send SMS to)

> Test Credentials
>
> If you received this error while trying to authenticate with your Test
>   Credentials, you probably tried to send a message with a From number
>   from your live account. The only number that can be used to send
>   successful messages with your Test Credentials is +15005550006. For
>   more information, read our documentation on the From number for
>   sending SMS with your test credentials.

Comment: Thanks now error is resolved, but I'm not receiving any message from twilo. The noumber to which I'm sending message is verified in twilo.